# There are $n$ balls $b_1,b_2,...b_n$ and $n$ boxes.Each ball is placed in a box chosen independently and uniformly at random.

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$  balls $b_1,b_2,...b_n$ and $n$  boxes.Each ball is placed in a box chosen independently and uniformly at random.We say $b_i,b_j$ is a colliding pair if $i<j$, and $b_i,b_j$ are placed in the same box.What is the expected number of colliding pairs?

I was trying to bring a summation which looked like this

$n {n \choose 2}+n {{n-1} \choose 2}(n-1)+....$

But it is quite urduous to calculate the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lineality of expectation, what is the probability that a pair $i<j$ is coliding? it is clearly $\frac{1}{n}$.

Hence the expected number of coliding pairs is $\binom{n}{2}/n=\frac{n-1}{2}$

Comment: I am just a rookie in probability..Can you explain what is lineality of expectation?

Comment: Let $X$ be the random variable defined as the number of colliding pairs. You want to find the expected value of $X$. We now define some other random variables. For every pair $i<j$ define $X_{i,j}$ as $1$ if $i,j$ is coliding and $0$ otherwise. It is clear that $X=\sum\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n}X_{i,j}$. And by Lineality of expectation you have $E(X)=\sum\limits_{1\leq i < j\leq n}E(X_{i,j})$. But since $X_{i,j}$ is an indicator variable its expectation is just the probability that it is $1$. This probability is $\frac{1}{n}$. Therefore $\sum\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n}E(X_{i,j})=\binom{n}{2}/n$

Comment: Why do we have to define $X_{i,j}=1$ for $i<j$ ?.Is it a property?Why is the probability $\frac{1}{n}$? For indicator function?

Comment: Look at it this way, suppose you have $\binom{n}{2}$ coins, and for each the probability they come up heads is $\frac{1}{n}$. What is the expected number of heads? This is the same, except each coin is a pair $i<j$ and we say that the pair comes up "heads" if it is colliding.